# clearInterval(intervalId) just stops the interval, it doesn't really clear it

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am not really sure how to tackle this as I don't understand what I am doing wrong - so, every time I click on created "start" button, a setInterval is triggered:

```
$("#questBox").on("click", "#startQuestButton", function(){
    document.getElementById("startQuestButton").classList.add("hidden");
    var requiredTime = 10000;
    var timer = 0;

    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(timer>requiredTime){
            clearInterval(interval)
            document.getElementById("startQuestButton").classList.remove("hidden");
        }
        timer+=1000; 
    }, 1000);
}
```

And the startQuestButton is a div, present in my html file:

```
<div id="startQuestButton"></div>
```

Now, when I click on the start button the second time, 2 identical setIntervals are triggered, 3 the third time and so on.
I have even tried to set the interval to null before and after I click on the start button. Also, the start button is hidden for as long as the interval is in process. I want to completely destroy the previous interval so that only one gets triggered as I press t the start button.
I need setInterval to display a progress bar, that imitates a loading bar (so, every second, the width of a colored element is enlarged by a few pixels).

Comment: Stopping and clearing an interval is the same thing - I assume the problem is with the button that starts the interval, so you’ll have to show the code for that.

Comment: Could you provide more source code and perhaps any relevant HTML? Not enough information is provided in order to provide a suitable answer.

Comment: can u demo ur code by codepen or jsbin? So it is clear

Comment: It sounds like you just need to call `clearInterval()` before you call `setInterval()` when you click the start button.

Comment: I added the html button code and the onclick function.
I called clearInterval() in number of places and it never changed anything.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `setInteval()` doesn't return an interval object (no such thing exists afaik) but it's id
so when you clear you clear only the last one created because it is the id saved in `interval`

```js
var requiredTime = 2000;
var timer = 0;

var interval

function createInterval() {
  interval = setInterval(function(){
      if(timer>requiredTime){
          console.log(`cleared interval : ${interval}`)
          clearInterval(interval)
      }
      timer+=500; 
  }, 500);
  console.log(`created interval : ${interval}`)
}

document.getElementById("b").onclick = createInterval
```

```html
<button id="b">clickMe</button>
```

to have only one at a time the idea is to clear before recreating

```js
var requiredTime = 2000;
var timer = 0;

var interval

function createInterval() {
  // as pointed by Barmar the if here is not useful in production since clearInterval with a parameter that is not an interval id do nothing silently
  // I only keep it to prevent this snippets to log "cleared interval : undefined"
  if(interval) {
    clearInterval(interval)
    console.log(`cleared interval : ${interval}`)
  }
  
  interval = setInterval(function(){
      if(timer>requiredTime){
          clearInterval(interval)
          console.log(`cleared interval : ${interval}`)
      }
      timer+=500; 
  }, 500);
  console.log(`created interval : ${interval}`)
}

document.getElementById("b").onclick = createInterval
```

```html
<button id="b">clickMe</button>
```

Comment: You don't really need `if(interval)`. `clearInterval()` does nothing if you call it with an argument that isn't an interval ID.

Comment: @Barmar I added to prevent the snippets logging `cleared inteval undefined`

Comment: Yeah, it's really only useful for the debugging statements, not the production code.

Comment: @Barmar added a comment to warn others ;)

Comment: @jonatjano Wow, I followed your example and I got it to work as inteded. Thanks a lot. :)